# Transform table to show standard deviations with mean in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to group by an ID and display the mean for a given time period as well as a list of the standard deviations (1sd, 2sd, 3sd)

```
id  start       end         diff  percent   date
a   4/1/2019    5/1/2019    160   11        04-01-2019 to 05-01-2019
a   5/1/2019    6/1/2019    136   8         05-01-2019 to 06-01-2019
a   6/1/2019    7/1/2019    174   9         06-01-2019 to 07-01-2019
b   4/1/2019    5/1/2019    112   5         04-01-2019 to 05-01-2019
b   5/1/2019    6/1/2019    141   6         05-01-2019 to 06-01-2019
```

Desired output

```
id  mean       st.deviation   sd1          sd2      sd3
a   156.6      19.2           137.4        118.2    99                        
b   126.5      20.5           106          86.4     65




Standard deviation sd1 = mean - 1(19.2) 
                   sd2 = mean - 2(19.2)
                   sd3 = mean - 3(19.2)
```

This is what I am doing:

```
import pandas
import numpy
import math
import sys

def sd_calc(df):
    n = len(df)

    if n <= 1:
        return 0.0

    mean, sd = avg_calc(df), 0.0

    # calculate stan. dev.
    for el in df:
        sd += (float(el) - mean)**2
    sd = math.sqrt(sd / float(n-1))

    return sd
```

I am able to calculate the standard deviation, but not sure how to incorporate within the Pandas
dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try `std` with `groupby`

```
out = df.groupby('id')['diff'].agg(['mean','std'])
Out[44]: 
          mean        std
id                       
a   156.666667  19.218047
b   126.500000  20.506097
```

For std1 to std3 , you can create by

```
out['std1'] = out['mean'] - out['std']
```